# Android: Periodically change the Text of a TextView of a Custom ListView

Tags: android, listview, timertask

In a Custom ListView i have a TextView whose Text must change periodically every 1 min, to the Current Time and Date.

So i did this:

```
Timer mTimer = new Timer();
mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
@Override
public void run() {

currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
(holder.myText).setText(new Date(currentTime));
}
}, 0, 60000);
```

in the getView of the Custom Adapter.

It works for the First time, because getView is called when setting the Adapter for the 1st time.

Next time it gives Exception:

**android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.**

so where exactly should i use this code?

If my practice itself is bad, please give me an idea how to achieve this.

Thank You

Comment: If you want to update UI in a thread, use runOnUiThread

Comment: i think even a handler works fine

Comment: @Sharath This: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/UI/TimingActivity.htm in the getView()??

Comment: yes write the handler logic in the getview()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't update a UI object from a Thread that is not the UI Thread.
Try this:

```
this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
   @Override
   public void run(){
       //update your TextView here
   }   
})
```

Comment: But how to make this runOnUiThread a Scheduled one. I mean How can i run this every 1 min?

Comment: Take a look at Android Handlers. Specially at the postDelayed method ;)

Comment: take a look at java.util.Timer

Answer (score 1):

You can also try the example in the following link.

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/UI/TimingActivity.htm

Comment: Please don't post links. Instead, show a few lines of code explaining what it does (in that case, `Handler.postDelayed(...)`.